# Application Crash cleared the content of the Folder

Tags: files, data-recovery

Recently while working on the LinuxDC++ over the network the application crashed while downloading files. Now my Downloads folder which had at least 60-80GB of data is completely cleaned but the system is not reporting the available the correct free space. Is there way to restore the contents of the folder only as the solution available are for the whole partition.
I just want to recover the contents from one folder.

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `gksudo nautilus`, browse to the file system, and tell us whether there are files in `/lost+found` and a guess for the total size.

Comment: I have restarted my system since then but there are no files present in the /lost+found.Please help if I can at least restore any part of it.

Comment: Have you tried running an `fsck`? Also, have you tried going to the folder where the files are missing from and tried looking for hidden files with Ctl+H?

Comment: Tried that but its just reporting that there no problem with my filesystem. also tried to use Ctrl+H to see if the file have become hidden but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks you ObsessiveFOSS for your help & tips to locate a solution to my problem I have been able to locate my missing files. As it turned out that the application itself while downloading the files from DC Network uses a temporary directory to stores files. While I was browsing through the filesystem I just stumbled upon this temporary folder while looking through it I found all my files(hopefully all!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out that the application itself while downloading the files from DC Network uses a temporary directory to stores files. While I was browsing through the filesystem I just stumbled upon this temporary folder (For LinuxDC++ it under /home//.dc++/FileLists) while looking through it I found most of my files.